# How do Capture Groups Beyond \9 get Referenced in R?

Tags: regex, r

Is it possible in R to capture groups >9 in a regular expression?

```
sub("(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)", "\\1 & \\9",   
    "abc-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09")
```

gives

```
[1] "abc & 09"
```

which is expected result, but

```
sub("(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)", "\\1 & \\10",   
    "abc-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10")

[1] "abc & abc0"
```

fails, as the expected result would have been

```
[1] "abc & 10"
```

I need this for a function like the following, which works fine for up to 9 formats but no more:

```
x <- as.Date(c("2005-09-02", "2012-04-08"))

fmt <- "dddd, d.m.yy"

fmt <- gsub(pattern = "dddd", replacement = "\\\\1", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "ddd", replacement = "\\\\2", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "dd", replacement = "\\\\3", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "d", replacement = "\\\\4", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "mmmm", replacement = "\\\\5", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "mmm", replacement = "\\\\6", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "mm", replacement = "\\\\7", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "m", replacement = "\\\\8", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "yyyy", replacement = "\\\\9", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "yy", replacement = "\\\\10", x = fmt)
fmt <- gsub(pattern = "y", replacement = "\\\\11", x = fmt)
fmt

sub("(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-0?(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-0?(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-0?(.+)", fmt, 
    format(x, "%A-%a-%d-%d-%B-%b-%m-%m-%Y-%y-%y"))
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to do this using a regular expression?  Seems like splitting the string based on "-" might be more appropriate in this case

Comment: This says it is possible for up to 99 capturing groups http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html, but so far I'm having no luck with those over `\\9`

Comment: @RichardScriven `?regex` says "The backreference ‘\N’, where ‘N = 1 ... 9’, matches the substring previously matched by the Nth parenthesized subexpression of the regular expression." So I think we're limited to only 9...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers so far. I need this for a format function, which formats dates by means of format codes like dddd, ddd, dd, d, mmmm, mmm, mm etc. all in all 11 codes. And so I thought I could build a big string with all possible single formats like () and sub them... strsplit will be much slower in connection with sapply, but I'll try that.

Comment: Ok, looking at that, I was maybe a bit lazy... I could  of course check for the used format codes and build the regex accordingly. Using all 11 codes in one and the same expression might rather be a rare event..

Answer (score 4):

Its important to note that the limit is nine *backreferences*; you get unlimited captures.  By using [`str_match`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_match) from `stringr` (or, more clunkily, [`regmatches`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/regmatches) from base R), you can always restructure your code to avoid having to use backreferences.

```
library(stringr)
(matches <- str_match(
  "abc-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10", 
  "(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)")
)
##      [,1]                             [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
## [1,] "abc-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10" "abc" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09"  "10" 
paste(matches[, 2], matches[, 11], sep = " & ")
## [1] "abc & 10"
```

Answer (score 2):

As Dason indicates, you're better off splitting the string and taking the desired elements.

```
elements <- c(1,10)
paste(strsplit("abc-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10", '-')[[1]][elements], collapse=' & ')
## [1] "abc & 10"
```

This can be vectorized with `sapply`, if needed:

```
sapply(strsplit("abc-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10", '-'), function(x) paste(x[elements], collapse=' & '))
```